# SVR: Predicted values are way off from the actual ones despite high r-squared and and low MSE

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I have trained a SVR model using scikit learn that predicts the future price of bitcoin by using its closing price on previous dates. I have converted date into delta from the first available date using the following function:

```
btc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(btc['Date'])     
btc['date_delta'] = (btc['Date'] - btc['Date'].min())  / np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

My dataframe's head looks something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>date_delta</th>
    <th>Close</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1654.0</td>
    <td>7144.38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1653.0</td>
    <td>7022.76</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I do split into test and training dataset as follows:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(btc_select)) < 0.8
btc_train = btc_select[msk]
btc_test = btc_select[~msk]
```

and do min max scaling of the dataset before training the model as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(btc_train)
btc_train = scaler.transform(btc_train)
btc_test = scaler.transform(btc_test)
```

My model is trained using the following function and I find polynomial kernel gives he best result:

```
def predict_prices(dates_train, prices_train, dates_test, price_test):
    dates_train=np.reshape(dates_train, (len(dates_train),1))
    dates_test=np.reshape(dates_test, (len(dates_test),1))
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel = 'poly', C=1e3, degree=8)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.8)
    svr_lin.fit(dates_train,prices_train)
    svr_poly.fit(dates_train,prices_train)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates_train,prices_train)
    plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
    plt.scatter(dates_train, prices_train, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates_train, svr_rbf.predict(dates_train), color='red', label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(dates_train, svr_lin.predict(dates_train), color='green', label='Linear model')
    plt.plot(dates_train, svr_poly.predict(dates_train), color='blue', label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    print('Lin Score:', svr_lin.score(dates_test, price_test))
    print('Poly Score:', svr_poly.score(dates_test, price_test))
    print('Rbf Score:', svr_rbf.score(dates_test, price_test))
    scores = cross_val_score(svr_poly, dates_train, prices_train, cv=6, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
    accuracy = metrics.r2_score(price_test, svr_poly.predict(dates_test))
    print('R-Squared Value for the Polynomial Kernel:', accuracy)
    print('Cross Validation Mean Squared Error for the Polynomial Kernel:', scores)
    return svr_poly
```

I get the following accuracy and cross validation scores:

```
Lin Score: 0.3290332147578777
Poly Score: 0.8724266575682722
Rbf Score: 0.836449334307112
R-Squared Value for the Polynomial Kernel: 0.8724266575682722
Cross Validation Mean Squared Error for the Polynomial Kernel: [-0.13853584 -0.00069995 -0.00043713 -0.00041959 -0.00341142 -0.00352207]
```

But when I try to predict the btc price for a datapoint after transforming the date_delta and inverse transforming the predicted output the results are way off. Need help as to what is going wrong.

```
transform_inp = scaler.transform([[1654.0,0.0]])
transform_inp[0,0]
1.000604960677556

predicted_val = model.predict(np.array(transform_inp[0,0]))
predicted_val
array([0.73674025])
```

Now doing the inverse transform I get the following:

```
scaler.inverse_transform([[predicted_val[0],0]])
array([[1217.83164131,   68.43      ]])
```

The output is 1217 USD which is way off from the actual price of 7144 USD. Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Many things to say:

1. I don't really understand what your objective is: basically, you try to match a number of days from an origin date with the price of btc which are actually unrelated (the numerical value of the delta is completely independent). You'd better try to match the price of btc of a given day, with the prices of btc of the few previous days
2. You split your train/test data by picking randomly 80% for training. Why don't you use the first 80% points for learning and the last 20% for predicting ? In your current configuration, are biased by the way data are sampled
3. Now imagine your model overfits (it learns a very complex date_delta/price curve) that fits you training points well. It is very likely that the predictions on test data will be far from the truth. Try to vary the parameter of the support vector regression.

Still your result is too far from what it should. I might ask where did you take the value 1654.0 ? And did you look at the results with the linear model ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe SVR is not the best model for this kind of analysis because even if I split the date into year, day, month the result is still off.
1654 was a random value of date offset that I put in to check the result.
Regarding random splitting, I agree we can split sequentially.
I am thinking about trying LSTM for the same analysis.

Comment: What I mean is that if your training deltas are between 0 and 1000, and you finally gives 1600 to your model, you can't expect it to give a good prediction, because you don't tackle the problem the right way. You shouldn't try to fit the date anyway, except if you just want to see what shape the fitted curve has.